# Process variable number of arguments in Lua

Tags: lua, arguments

I am passing arguments to a Lua script and retrieving them using:

```
local arg1, arg2 = ...
```

Now I'd like to use a different syntax, with free ordering, such that I can call:

```
./myscript.lua arg1=val1 arg2=val2
```

so I'm trying something like:

```
args = ...
params = {}

for i, k in pairs(args) do
  p, v = split(a, "=")
  params[p] = v
end
```

which doesn't work because `args` only gets the value of the first argument.

How can I retrieve all the arguments passed to the script in one go?

Note: the script is executed from C using `lua_pcall`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign it with `{...}` like this:

```
args = {...}
params = {}

for i, k in ipairs(args) do
  print(i, k)
end
```

In fact, `args` is not needed:

```
for i, k in ipairs{...} do
```